docker-compose starts sonarqube and reports an error: `Fail to execute es requestES indices exists request on indices 'xxx'
my server has about 2G of memory, and when I try to start sonar with minimum memory, I keep getting errors such as: Fail to execute es requestES indices exist request on indices 'metadatas'. this error seems to be caused by a problem with the built-in es index, but I checked es.log and there was no error message. is it because my memory is too small?
this's my docker-compose.yml
version: "3"

services:
    sonarqube:
      image: sonarqube:10.6-community
      ports:
        - "9000:9000"
      depends_on:
        - db
      environment:
        SONAR_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
        SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: sonar
        SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: sonar
        SONAR_ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms256m -Xmx256m"
      volumes:
        - /data/sonar/data:/opt/sonarqube/data
        - /data/sonar/logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
        - /data/sonar/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions

    db:
      image: postgres
      ports:
        - 5433:5432
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: sonar
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonar
        POSTGRES_DB: sonar
      volumes:
        - /data/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
        - /data/postgresql/logs:/var/lib/postgresql/data

this's my error content
2024.08.26 03:25:09 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@691939c9-org.sonar.server.es.IndexCreator': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.sonar.server.es.ElasticsearchException: Fail to execute es requestES create index 'projectmeasures'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:929)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:225)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:80)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel4.start(PlatformLevel4.java:701)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.start(PlatformImpl.java:214)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.startLevel34Containers(PlatformImpl.java:194)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl$AutoStarterRunnable.runIfNotAborted(PlatformImpl.java:362)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl$1.doRun(PlatformImpl.java:113)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl$AutoStarterRunnable.run(PlatformImpl.java:346)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.sonar.server.es.ElasticsearchException: Fail to execute es requestES create index 'projectmeasures'
        at org.sonar.server.es.EsClient.execute(EsClient.java:336)
        at org.sonar.server.es.EsClient.create(EsClient.java:196)
        at org.sonar.server.es.IndexCreator.createIndex(IndexCreator.java:142)
        at org.sonar.server.es.IndexCreator.lambda$start$1(IndexCreator.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.server.es.IndexCreator.start(IndexCreator.java:92)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.StartableBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(StartableBeanPostProcessor.java:33)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:922)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:300)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:288)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2699)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2171)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2154)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2118)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create(IndicesClient.java:152)
        at org.sonar.server.es.EsClient.lambda$create$22(EsClient.java:196)
        at org.sonar.server.es.EsClient.execute(EsClient.java:334)
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed
        at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.endOfInput(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:356)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:261)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)

